# Select a string from a string-array in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, r.java-file

So I have a file like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="item_types">
        <item>Dry Food</item>
        <item>Produce</item>
        <item>Frozen Good</item>
        <item>Household Item</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And I am making a `Dialog` with some selection on it. I want to reuse these values in my layout. I would like to use them through my resources `R`. I would like to set this value I select from `R` to the `android:text` of an element.

Something like this in my mind...

```
...
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@R.arrays.item_types.0" />
...
```

Obviously this does not work. I plan on making this `Dialog` programmatically in the future, but was wondering if I could set this text in the XML. I also plan on that array being changed by the user. So it would be nice if I did not have to statically define the text in the `TextView`.

I have a good idea of how I will do it in java. Just wondering if this could be done in one go via xml.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_types);

set the text of TextView programmatically (using TextView.setText) by accessing list[0] in java

Comment: Thing is, he want to do it directly on the xml.